# Clear bluetooth devices list in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

I had bluetooth enabled while I was at my university. Little did I know, my Windows 8 laptop was keeping a record of all bluetooth devices it could find. Now, I have a monstrous list of bluetooth devices in my settings panel, and I can only get rid of them one by one!

[image: Bluetooth Devices List]

Is there a way to clear my bluetooth devices list? I only have my phone and a bluetooth mouse, so it's very obnoxious to scroll through hundreds of devices to find the ones that I own.

Comment: Microsoft does not say how to remove all by one click. You may try to go to `Device manager` (via `Control Panel` -> `System`) and there check `Show Hidden Device` in `View Menu`. It is possible that all devices (even these BT) will be listed - this way I am able to remove e.g. Mobile Devices. But still you will have to remove one by one. You could also check the registry - but that may be tricky.

Comment: Registry could be: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTHENUM` and `BTH`

Answer (score 0):

Search for the bluetooth device name in regedit.
i found the list here
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\SWD\DAFUPnPProvider
delete them all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).